# How can I take the value of a button and put it as the header of another page in Flask?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

In my `index.html`, I prompt the user to enter a name which creates a button with the name on it. When clicked, it leads to `inside_goal.html`

```
<script>
  var counter = 0;
  function createButton(){
      var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
      x.className = "second";
      x.id = "first";
      var name = document.querySelector("#goal").value;
      var t = document.createTextNode(name);
      x.appendChild(t);
      document.getElementById("space_holder").appendChild(x);
      var insideclass = document.getElementsByClassName("second");
      insideclass[counter].innerHTML = `<input type="button" onclick="location.href='/inside_goal'" value="${name}"/>`;
      counter = counter+1;
      document.querySelector("#goal").value = "";
  
  };
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id = "home_header" style = "font-family: optima; text-align: center"> Nancy Dong </h1>
  <div id = "enter.goal">
    <form action = /inside_goal id = "subBox" onsubmit = "createButton(); return false;">
      <input name = "name",  type = "text", id = "goal">
      <input type = "submit", value = "Enter Goal">
    </form>
  </div>
```

`inside_goal.html`

```
<body>
  <h1 id = "h1">
    testing {{ name }} !!!
  </h1>
</body>
```

My `flask` looks like

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
        return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/inside_goal")
def names():
     name = request.args.get('name')
     return render_template("inside_goal.html", name = name)
```

I want `inside_goal.html` to have the same header as the button that was clicked on. However, the heading is currently returning "testing None". The get request couldn't get the name.

I also tried

```
var test = "";
$("button).click(function(){
    test = $(this).val();
    alert(test); 
})
```

to test out if I could get button values that way, but only got the initialization value.

I'm fairly new to web development, so I might be missing some concepts. Any help is appreciated!